# PDF Viewer in Qt

Tags: qt, pdf, viewer, reader

I am trying to create a pdf viewer inside qt using Adobe Readers ActiveX, but it requires to install Adobe Reader, so is it possible without installing Adobe reader we can create pdf viewer

Comment: Which platform(s)?  Is [Poppler](https://poppler.freedesktop.org/) an option -- it has integration layers for both `Qt4` and `Qt5`?

Comment: yes i think Poppler is also one option but i don't know steps for Poppler. but i know the Adobe Readers steps its very simpale , but the problem is it is dependant. i need to run it independatly means only inside Qt

Comment: Well, if you follow the link I provided it will get you [here](https://people.freedesktop.org/~aacid/docs/qt5/) which has a very straightforward example.

Comment: Thank you, but in this steps i am not able to include #include <poppler-qt5.h>  **says no such file or directory**

Comment: Use your favorite search engine: https://wiki.qt.io/Handling_PDF

Comment: You can use [Qt Web Engine](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/webengine-examples.html), which allows you to use a web browser in your Qt program. It can also open PDF files.

Answer (score 8):

[QtPdf](http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt-labs/qtpdf.git) module in the Qt Labs.

It comes with a Widgets-based PdfViewer example, which works out of the box.

It can be easily incorporated into any Qt app - We are incorporating it into one if our QML applications, by creating a wrapper.

Qt blog announcement [here](http://blog.qt.io/blog/2017/01/30/new-qtpdf-qtlabs-module).

Comment: @MahdiKhalili feel free to use whatever you like. qpdf was a bit big for what I needed... just displaying some pages

Comment: ... but not cross platform like the other 2

Comment: i never been able to compile QtPdf to be able to use it

Comment: it wont compile on windows vs17 for some kind of define sprintf used in code need to use vs15 for it

Comment: I have only used QtPdf with g++