# Qt5 - Simple PDF-Viewer

Tags: qt, pdf, qt5, qtgui

In my application I have a toolbar with different buttons (load a file, print, help/about etc). With the button Help/About I want to show a .pdf-File, which is the manual of my application.
Is there simple way to show a pdf in Qt?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PDF Viewer in Qt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44521053/pdf-viewer-in-qt)

Comment: You probably want to take a look at [`poppler`](https://poppler.freedesktop.org/).

Comment: Just downloaded poppler, included it in my project and wanted to test it:      `QString url = QString(":manual/resources/manual/Manual.pdf");
    Poppler::Document *document = Poppler::Document::load(url);
    if(!document || document->isLocked())
    {
        qDebug() << "pdf locked";
        delete document;
        return;
    }` , but i get "undefinied reference to ..", in  every line  where the "document" is. I think I'd have to add something in my .pro-file or?

Comment: Sounds like you're just including Poppler's headers, but don't link to Poppler's library file.

Comment: What I've done in my .pro-file now: `LIBS += -L/usr/lib -lpoppler-qt5                                                                             INCLUDEPATH += \ ../../library/Poppler/qt5/src \                                               HEADERS += \ ../../library/Poppler/qt5/src/poppler-qt5.h  \ `    but, it still doesnt work, warning now: cannot find -lpoppler-qt5